# How to make Mocha's grep option work in browser

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to write BDD tests in browser. I would like the ability to run selective tests using Mocha's grep option. Mocha has grep support when launched from command line for node.js environment. However I can't get it to work for the browser.

I am setting up Mocha as shown in these [example](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/tree/master/test/browser) html file and tried to pass grep as option, but that didn't work

```
mocha.setup({ui:"bdd",ignoreLeaks:true,grep:"pattern"})
mocha.run()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured it out.

You can mention the grep option in the URL like this

```
/?grep=pattern
```

If you want to launch tests programmatically you need to make sure that `window.location.search` reads `?grep=pattern`.

Directly setting window.location.search to some string may not be desirable because that refreshes the page. Instead you can use HTML5 history API `window.history.pushState({},'Test','/?grep=pattern')` before calling `mocha.run()`

Comment: Clicking on one of the test suite entries in the browser (which are created by the *describe* blocks) causes a page reload with grep. One can see that the grep pattern uses and combine nested *describe* block names.